# permission denied for basic commands

Tags: permissions, scientific-linux

I'm trying to create a directory in my home directory and I'm getting a permission denied warning. I am in /home/User/ as most solutions suggest. I'm also aware that I could use:

```
sudo mkdir
```

I also discovered in working around the problem that I can no longer use mv, cp, or rm without the sudo command. I was able to run all of these commands without problem before I added myself to the sudoers file. Did I remove myself from some permissions somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `whoami`, `id -nG`, and `ls -ld $HOME $PWD`

Comment: @steeldriver I tried Aaron's suggestions before I got to this. whoami returns user name and id -nG returned: Username, and sudoers group. Both of these were the same before I tried Aaron's solution. I assume the permissions shown with ls -ld are different now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `sudo chown $(whoami) ~` and also `sudo chmod -R u=rwx ~`. This should set your home directory as owned by you and give yourself all permissions.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Any idea how I would have lost the permissions in the first place?

Comment: You probably just accidentally ran a command that you shouldn't have. I doubt this could've been anything other than a manually-caused accident.